# How to access lookup object value using Salesforce composite connector "Create sobject tree" in Mule 4

Tags: salesforce, mulesoft, mule4

I want to insert data into 2 objects (say Employee__c and Contacts) which have parent-child relation using the Salesforce Composite Connector method **Create sobject tree**. Few fields have a lookup object. I want to pass the external ID field value to this lookup object and fetch the value. But it looks like **Create sobject tree** doesn't support using lookup logic. Can someone shed light on how this can be achieved?

Sample Code that I tried. In the Employee__c table, I have an Account__c field that has a lookup to Account object and here I am trying to reference that using the external ID field. I know for lookup we need to use as Account__r, this works in normal Salesforce connector but it is not working in the composite connector.

```
payload.records map ((record , indexOfRecord) -> {
    "attributes": {
        "type": "Employee__c",
        "referenceId": record.attributes.referenceId
    },
    "Name": record.Name,
    "Website": record.Website,
    **"Account__r": {
        'Employee_Number__c': record.EmployeeNumber, 
        'type': 'Account'
    }**,
    "Contacts": {
        "records": record.Contacts.records map ((record01, indexOfRecord01) -> {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Contact",
                "referenceId": record01.attributes.referenceId
            },
            "LastName": record01.LastName,
            "Email": record01.Email,
            "Title": record01.Title
        })
    }
})
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check if my answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/274696/799 and comments help you?

Comment: Thanks this helped alot :-). I have another question on lookup. Is it possible to retrieve lookup value from a standard object (with external Id) to another standard Object?
For example, in Contacts object I have standard field AccountId which has a lookup Account (where I have an external ID field like AccountName__c). Similar to my above sample, but instead of custom field Account__r I want to get value for standard field AccountId
"AccountId": {
        'AccountName__c': "GenPoint", 
        'type': 'Account'
    }

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by retrieve, query the tables? Joins in SF look "object-oriented", you could go `SELECT Id, LastName, AccountId, Account.Id, Account.Name, Account.AccountNumber__c FROM Contact` and see what it returns. In this example "AccountId" is a foreign key field on Contact but "Account.anyFieldNameHere" represents the join... Like table alias in normal database if that helps you? Give https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using.htm a go. You can even `SELECT Account.Owner.Profile.Name FROM Contact`.